# Reversing order of data while keeping suborder together in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

So I have a bunch of excel files with 3 columns of data and currently they are listed in order of 2016 to 1990, with an entry for each month. What I need to do is reverse the order of the years while keeping the order of the months for each year intact but I have no idea how to do so.

I tried figuring out how to group each year so I could potentially then reverse the order of the groups but I can't figure out a way faster then manually going in and grouping each of the years which isn't much better then just copy pasting them in a new order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a custom Sort.

starting with this:

[image]

with a cell in your table selected, click on Sort & Filter & select Custom Sort
Fill it out like this (use Add level to get the second line, for Order on month, use Custom list):

[image]

Click OK and you'll get this:

[image]

This example has just two years, but it will work with any number, assuming values are contiguous in your table. If you use numbers instead of names for your months, just choose the appropriate Order.

Comment: Thanks man this helped a lot, bit hectic so sorry about not replying earlier. Didn't have year marks for everything so I just setup a list I could paste over for each of the excel files and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If this solved the problem, feel free to mark this as the "accepted answer."